# Primary Decomposition - No Further Decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Please note that this is an assignment question.

Let $T : V \rightarrow V$ be a linear transformation of finite dimension vector spaces over an arbitrary field $F$.  Assume that $p(x) = p_{1}(x)\cdots p_{r}(x)$ is the factorization of the minimal polynomial into monic irreducible factors.

We know that $V = V_{1} \oplus ... \oplus V_{r}$ which are stable under $T$ and such that the restriction $T_{j}$ of $T$ to $V_{j}$ has $p_{j}(x)$ as the minimal polynomial.

I was able to get this question through a proof by induction on $r$ easily. However, the part that I'm having trouble with is showing:

If $\dim(V_{k}) = \deg(p_{j})$ show that $V_{j}$ cannot be further decomposed into a direct sum of $T$ stable vector spaces.

My idea for the proof was to show by a contradiction that by assuming your space $V_{j}$ could be further decomposed than you would get that $p_{j}(x)$ wasn't irreducible because you would be the multiplication of the minimal polynomials on each of its further decomposition would divide it.  However, you are only able to show that $p_{j}(x)$ divides the multiplication instead of the other way around.

Any tips as to how to go about showing this?  We know that the decomposition by the primary decomposition theorem is unique, but I don't think that is relevant here.

Comment: Ended up getting it, simply have to show that one of the reduced minimal polynomials has to be 1 inducing a zero subspace!